# Falha ao enviar email ASP

Tags: asp.net, email, asp

Tenho o seguinte código para envio de e-mails, porém ele está dando erro, não informa da muita informação apenas aparece "Falha ao enviar email.", eu já mudei a porta, alterei `EnableSsl` para `true` e depois para `false`, o código é o seguinte:

```
string nomeRemetente = "Contato";
        string emailRemetente = "webmaster@.com.br";
        string assuntoMensagem = assunto;
        MailMessage objEmail = new MailMessage();
        objEmail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(nomeRemetente + "<" + emailRemetente + ">");
        foreach (var dest in destinatarios)
        {
            objEmail.To.Add(new MailAddress(dest));
        }
        objEmail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("email@.com.br"));
        objEmail.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.Normal;
        objEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        objEmail.Subject = assuntoMensagem;
        objEmail.Body = conteudoMensagem;
        objEmail.From = new MailAddress(emailRemetente);
        objEmail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
        objEmail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient objSmtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        objSmtp.Host = "smtp..com.br";
        objSmtp.EnableSsl = true;
        objSmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        objSmtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        objSmtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(objEmail.From.ToString(), "senha");
        objSmtp.Port = 587;

        try
        {
            objSmtp.Send(objEmail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            objEmail.Dispose();
        }
```

O erro ocorre no `objSmtp.Send(objEmail);`

Comment: Precisa de mais informações. Provavelmente tem algo útil na stack trace ou nas inner exceptions.

Comment: @guilherme-alves esse problema pode também ser do firewall da sua rede

Comment: Poste a mensagem e o StackTrace do erro que acontece.

Comment: @KevenCarneiro Get general help for this exception
InnerException: Check the Status property of the exception to determine why the request failed
InnerException: Check the Response property of the exception to determine why the request failed
Get general help for the inner exception

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tenta colocar uma virgula após cada e-mail, deixando o último e-mail sem a virgula no fim.

Ex: NomeRemetente1 <"EmailRemetente1">, NomeRemetente2 <"EmailRemetente2">